# schema.org: Brand of a Product an Organization?

Tags: semantic-web, microdata, schema.org

We like to use HTML5 microdata in a website. But we are kind of puzzled how to apply the brand to our products. According to http://schema.org/Product, the brand is an Organization.

An example: If the iPhone is a brand of Apple Inc, how do I apply this to a iPhone 3GS product page?

Edit: I saw several examples providing a simple String as the brand, e.g. http://www.affiliatetuts.com/general/adding-microdata-to-your-markup/. Is that valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i markedup an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/GVuUw/  passed validation here: http://validator.nu/ and i got the information from: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC555

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see anything about the brand inside of your example.

Comment: sorry man, i should have read that more thoroughly. i added Apple Store and Apple branding to the markup and it validated. same link: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/GVuUw/5/

Comment: Okay, thanks. I found an answer to my initial question: http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected says "When browsing the schema.org types, you will notice that many properties have "expected types". This means that the value of the property can itself be an embedded item (see section 1d: embedded items). But this is not a requirement—it's fine to include just regular text or a URL."

Answer (score 1):

On the ability to include strings instead of full inline descriptions, see http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html

> "While we would like all the markup we get to follow the schema, in practice, we expect a lot of data that does not. We expect schema.org properties to be used with new types. We also expect that often, where we expect a property value of type Person, Place, Organization or some other subClassOf Thing, we will get a text string. In the spirit of "some data is better than none", we will accept this markup and do the best we can."